# Is $d$ a metric on $X$?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

let  $X= C^1([0,1], \mathbb{R})$ be the  space  of real value  contnious  function defined , differentiable and having  a  continious derivative   on $[0,1]$. define  a   function  fro $X \times X$  into $\mathbb{R}^{+}$  by

$d(f,g) = \sup_{x \in [0,1]} | f'(x) - g'(x)|$  where  $f '$ stand  for the derivative  of  $f$ .

Is  $d$  a metric  on $X$?

My attempt :yes, d is  ametric on $X$.  I take  $f(x) = x^2$ and $g(x) =x$. Then all metric  properties are satisfied

Is  its  true?

Any hints/ guidenace solution will be appreciated

thanks u

Comment: What if $f\equiv 0$ and $g\equiv 1$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Concentrate on the question whether $d(f,g)=0$ implies $f=g.$

Comment: Yes, but if you take $f(x) = x$ and $g(x)=x+1$ the condition $d(f,g)=0$ is also satisfied, even though the functions are different.

Comment: thanks u @Reiner  now i understands

Answer (score 1):

Another important point to make is that when you need to decide if something is a metric (or generally anything that has some "for all ..." qualifier), you need to actually **consider all functions if you want to prove that is indeed true**, while a single **counterexample to one part is enough to prove it is not true**.

That alone should make you understand that "it works for $f(x)=x^2, g(x)=x$" can *never* be proof for something that requires to work for all functions (with certain restrictions that leave more than those 2 functions in the considered set).